# Create a String from chars at indexes 0, 1, 4, 5, 8, 9

Tags: java, string

I have came across this problem on codingbat.com:

**Given a string, return a string made of the chars at indexes 0,1, 4,5, 8,9 ... so
"kittens" yields "kien".**

Here is my code:

```
public String altPairs(String str) {

  String result = "";

  for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    result += str.substring(i, i+1);

    if (i > 0 && str.indexOf(str.substring(i, i+1)) % 2 != 0) i += 2;
  }

  return result;
}
```

For **"CodingHorror"**, it should return **"Congrr"**.

---

- Why does my code return **"Congrro"** for the parameter **"CodingHorror"**?

Comment: Wouldnt you want to do i+=4 if you check each 4th element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be solved in a much simpler way:

```
String result = "";

for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i += 4) {
result += str.substring(i, Math.min(str.length(), i + 2));          
}

return result;
```

More:

- It's generally a bad idea to change counter variable inside a *for* loop - use *while* loop then.
- substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex) - *endIndex* is exclusive.

Comment: Look into modified code, please. Code should handle a situation, when endIndex is out of bounds!

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers You are right, its ambigous what to do with odd-length strings.

Answer (score 2):

First the second index of `substring` is exclusive. If you want 2 characters directly, you should use `i+2` instead of `i+1`:

```
str.substring(i, i+2)
```

Then, you just have to increment `i` by `4` at each loop turn. Use `i+=4` instead of `i++`, and you won't need the conditional increment.

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i+=4) {
    result += str.substring(i, i+2);
}
```

Or, if you allow to break a pair of characters at the end of the String:

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i+=4) {
    if (i < str.length() - 1)
        result += str.substring(i, i+2);
    else
        result += str.substring(i, i+1);
}
```

Comment: Be aware of possible `IndexOutOfBoundsException` here though, when String has length 5 you will end up calling `.substring(4,6)` which will throw that exception.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers Very true. I'll edit my answer. There are 2 possible solutions then, depending on the requirements.

Comment: Indeed. I do not know what should happen then, return only the first of the 2 characters or neither.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String altPairs(String str) {
  String newStr = "";
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
    {
      newStr = newStr +str.charAt(i);
      if(i%2!=0)
        i=i+2;
    }
  return newStr;
}
```

I did it this way
Inside loop add a condition
if i is odd then i=i+2;
which is increasing the value of i to +3 index

Answer (score -2):

check this out..

```
public String altPairs(String str) {
String result = "";
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ) {
result += str.substring(i, i+1);
i+=4;
}
return result;}
```

Comment: Buggy! Test on "CodingHor", please.

Comment: @VarunKarhadkar You did not check correctly, output for `"CodingHorror"` is `"Cnr"` with your method, due to `i+1` instead of `i+2`.

Comment: @VarunKarhadkar Yep, there is none. But it doesn't solve the task!